# How do I groupby multiple columns in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, max

I'm working board game data from BoardGameGeek, and I'd like to create a dataframe that groups board games by the minimum number of players AND by categories.

Here are the column names: ['name', 'category', 'playtime', 'playtime_num', 'avg_rating',
'num_ratings', 'min_players'].

I first created a new column called 'support_solo' based on 'min_players' that indicates whether or not the board game has support solo play or doesn't : 'support solo', 'not support solo'.

Then I created a groupby object:

```
grouped = popular.groupby(['support_solo', 'category'])
```

After that I called basic aggregate functions to get a breakdown of the number of games in each category, and for in each 'solo/not solo group', as well as average values for other fields such as playtime. However, I'm having trouble getting the game with the most number of ratings for each category. I used a helper function and a dictionary of all of the groupby aggregations:

```
def game_with_highest_ratings(group):
    max_ratings_index = group['num_ratings'].idxmax()
    return group.loc[max_ratings_index, 'name']

aggregations = {
    'name': 'count', # total number of games in each category
    'num_ratings': game_with_highest_ratings, # game with the most ratings in each category
    'avg_rating': 'mean', # average rating of games in each category
    'playtime_num': 'mean', # average playtime of games in each category
}

grouped_result = grouped.agg(aggregations)
```

I keep on getting KeyError: 'num_ratings', and I don't know how to fix this issue. I have already checked for correct column names. How can I fix this issue, or is there an alternative method?

Comment: Try `print(group)` inside `game_with_highest_ratings` and you'll see that your problem is that it just gets passed that column's data, not the entire dataframe.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? (And out of curiosity, can you share the code used to retrieve the BGG data?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`agg` passes only a Series to the function, not the full DataFrame. Trying to slice here would search in the **indices** (`group` is already 1D). You cannot access the other columns.

The most efficient workaround is likely to aggregate the `idxmax` and **then** to post-process it.

```
aggregations = {
    'name': 'count', # total number of games in each category
    'num_ratings': 'idxmax', # game with the most ratings in each category
    'avg_rating': 'mean', # average rating of games in each category
    'playtime_num': 'mean', # average playtime of games in each category
}

grouped_result = grouped.agg(aggregations)
grouped_result['num_ratings'] = grouped_result['num_ratings'].map(popular['name'])
```

A not-as-clean solution could be to use the hardcoded external reference in the function:

```
def game_with_highest_ratings(group):
    return popular.at[group.idxmax(), 'name']
```